# What is a variable in Java and why should I use it?

Tags: java, variables

I am creating an object and it should be used by another method.

How do I achieve this?

Here's my code:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass();
        myMethod();
    }

    public static void myMethod() {
        // Here's where I want to use my object
    }
}

public class MyClass {

}
```

Comment: Is this really a question that comes up on even a semi regular basis?

Comment: Absolutely. And they get answered every day. But they are all not generic enough to close each other.

Comment: @Cold Fire always double check.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: And none of those dozens of others are of sufficient quality?

Comment: @Cerbrus: IMHO they are too specific, have too much code and a beginner OP will not understand the crappy code of other beginners. This is an MCVE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two key elements you should know about:

- Use a **variable** to store the object and
- then pass it as a **parameter** to a method.

#### Part 1: a variable

After creating an object, you should store it in a variable. Otherwise it just exists in memory and will be garbage collected and thus be gone. Having a variable enables you to access it later and it will prevent it from being garbage collected as long as the variable exists (that's something about *scope*, you might want to make yourself familiar with that as well).

Variables have a type (`MyClass`) and a name and you use the `=` to assign it.

Here's the relevant part:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass object1 = new MyClass();       // <--- note the change
    myMethod();
}
```

You now have a variable named `object1` and you can use it with that name.

#### Part 2: a parameter

Now that you have a variable, you can "give" it to the method. We also say "pass". This is done in the parentheses like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass object1 = new MyClass();
    myMethod(object1);
}
```

At this time, your code will not run, because that method does not know anything about the parameter yet. Depending on the tool, you may see this immediately, e.g. by underlined text in Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse error message]]

To tell the method what it gets, you also define the type and a name there:

```
public static void myMethod(MyClass differentName) {
    // Here's where I want to use my object
}
```

Inside the method `myMethod`, note that the name of the variable can be different. This does not matter, the program just gives a different name to the exact same thing. My name is Alfred, but you can call me Al.

Inside `myMethod` you can use the variable under its new name only. Depending on what you want to do, you can access it by typing its name and a `.`. You can even pass it to other methods. Depending on the tool, you'll get suggestions on what you can do with it:

[image: Suggestions in Eclipse]

Comment: "Having a variable enables you to access it later and it will prevent it from being garbage collected as long as the variable exists". This is inaccurate. An object can be collected as soon as it is no longer reachable. This not only means that even if a variable is still in scope the object it refers to can be collected but also that an object that is not assigned to any variable could still not be eligible for collection.

Comment: @Voo: agreed, but that's too sophisticated for the intended use. People asking this question are absolute beginners they'll not understand

Comment: @ThomasWeller "People asking this question are absolute beginners" => This is an argument to be even more precise as such perople will adopt those statements without any further reflection.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose this might be arguable. It is a form of didactic reduction. You try to make the subject understandable for the audience, which sometimes requires you to be imprecise. At a later stage the people will reiterate over the principle with more knowledge and are ready to understand the whole depth of the problem.