# How to check if element is null before add it to list?

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, nullable

I have that code:

```
List<Move> list = new List<Move>();
list.Add(GetBeatingForFieldOnSpecificDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.TOP_LEFT));
list.Add(GetBeatingForFieldOnSpecificDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.TOP_RIGHT));
list.Add(GetBeatingForFieldOnSpecificDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.DOWN_LEFT));
list.Add(GetBeatingForFieldOnSpecificDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.DOWN_RIGHT));
```

The question is:
Is this possible to somehow check if this element is not null before add it to the list?
I mean **I don't want to call that method twice**. One call for check it is not null and another for eventually add it, this is a bad way, because I am writing an AI algorithm for computer and any resources are important.

Comment: Add `AddIfNotNull` extension method to `List<T>`. In the method, call `Add` if `!= null`.

Comment: `and any resources are important.` A `null` check is not going to make a meaningful impact on your execution time or resource usage.

Comment: If resources are important, the answer selected is an interesting choice. Since iterating through the list and creating a new list _might_ have an impact on resource usage.

Comment: Yes maybe but inside that list i will have only max 4 elements. So iterating through that list and  check if there was any nullable values won't be that as bad as it could be

Comment: So rather than checking an entry is null before adding it to a list, you want to instead **always** add it to a list. Then **later** check it is null and add it to a **second** list (if **not** null)? You know that must be slower, right? I am struggling to reconcile that with `because I am writing an AI algorithm for computer and any resources are important.`.

Comment: You are right, but since this list only has 4 items, it probably won't be such a tragedy. I don't have much time to deal with it because in 2 days I have to defend this project :D
I wanted to find some middle ground solution that somehow won't really impact resources

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a variable in Java and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764250/what-is-a-variable-in-java-and-why-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to just filter the list for non-null elements after adding them:

```
list = list.Where(l => l != null);
```

or possibly:

```
list = list.Where(l => l != null).ToList();
```

to materialize it to a `List<>` immediately, since `list` is explicitly a list type.

Comment: i think it will be the clearest way to achieve what i want... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value into a variable, check if it's null, and then add it to the list:

```
Move tmp = GetBeatingForFieldOnSpecificDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.TOP_LEFT);
if (tmp != null) {
    list.Add(tmp);
}
// The same can (should?) be done for the other moves
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Use the Try... out var -pattern.

```
private bool TryGetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(int i, Color enemyColor, Constant constant,
                                         out Move move)
{
    // pesudo code
    if (finds_a_diagonal) {
        move = get_some_move;
        return true;
    }
    move = null;
    return false;
}
```

Then

```
if (TryGetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.TOP_LEFT, out var m)) list.Add(m);
if (TryGetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.TOP_RIGHT, out m)) list.Add(m);
if (TryGetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.DOWN_LEFT, out m)) list.Add(m);
if (TryGetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.DOWN_RIGHT, out m)) list.Add(m);
```

---

**Solution 2:**

Use C#8.0 pattern matching and loop over the constants:

```
foreach (Constant c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Constant))) {
    if (GetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, c) is { } move) list.Add(move);
}
```

The pattern `{ } move` is an empty property pattern. It tests whether the returned value is not null and binds the result to the new variable `move`.

---

**Solution 3:**

The loop of solution 2 assumes that you want to loop over all the constants. If you don't want to do this, you can instead use this pattern matching four times.

```
if (GetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.TOP_LEFT) is { } m1) list.Add(m1);
if (GetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.TOP_RIGHT) is { } m2) list.Add(m2);
if (GetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.DOWN_LEFT) is { } m3) list.Add(m3);
if (GetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, Constant.DOWN_RIGHT) is { } m4) list.Add(m4);
```

---

**Solution 4:**

In C#8.0, you can also declare local functions, i.e., methods embedded within other methods.

```
void AddNonNullHitToList(Constant constant) // local function
{
    if (GetHitForFieldOnDiagonal(i, enemyColor, constant) is { } m) list.Add(m);
}

AddNonNullHitToList(Constant.TOP_LEFT);
AddNonNullHitToList(Constant.TOP_RIGHT);
AddNonNullHitToList(Constant.DOWN_LEFT);
AddNonNullHitToList(Constant.DOWN_RIGHT);
```

Note that this local function has access to the variables of the surrounding method (here `i`, `enemyColor` and `list`).